# RegEx Problem with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I would like to use the following regex with PHP to replace all repetitions of a character at the start of a string:

```
^.{3,5000}
```

If I use

```
echo preg_replace('#\^.{3,5000}#i', '', '------This is a test.');
```

will echo the text "------This is a test." although the regex itself works fine in any regex tester.

Bye,
Christian

Comment: Why did you add that backslash in front of the caret?  Now it matches a literal `^`, not the starting position of the string like you wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('#^(.)\1{3,5000}#', '', '------This is a test.');
?>
```

which will print:

```
This is a test.
```

as you can see on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/egLNp).

Note that the parenthesis around `.` store whatever is matched in group 1. This group 1 is then repeated between 3 and 5000 times. So, in total, it matches a minimum of 4 repeating characters. If you wanted to match at least 3 repeating characters (and an arbitrary amount after that), you could do something like this:

```
'#^(.)\1{2,}#'
```

*(by omitting the second integer value in `{2,}` you'll match any amount. In short, `{2,}` means: "two or more")*

Answer (score 0):

You've escaped the `^`! Change it to `^.{3,5000}` and it should work.

Comment: But that would just replace between 3 and 5000 characters (except line breaks) after the start-of-string, not just the repeating ones.

Comment: Sorry, he said it worked in regex testers in the first post so I didn't think :P

Comment: :), yeah, the `\^` is suspicious, although the regex engine does not produce any error message (which is probably what the OP meant by the fact that "it works").

Comment: @Bart: it's not suspicious, it's just wrong.  That's a perfectly normal escape sequence for a literal `^`, which is obviously not what the OP wants.